# Android device is shown as a portable device in windows 7 machine,

Tags: android, windows-7-x64, usb-drive, usb-debugging

Android device is shown as a portable device in windows 7 machine,therefore I'm unable to do usb debugging.

The android device is a Zigo tablet.

Comment: This question should be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should install ZigoTblet usb driver in your windows 7 machine.